# SQL Server 2008 R2 report manager URL not found

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Hi I tried to configure report manager URL and its something like this

```
http://developer_me/Reports
```

under reporting service configuration manager. I did all the configurations but when um trying to access it internet explorer tells that

```
  The webpage cannot be found
```

Anyone know the reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reporting Services provides default values for both application URLs that work well in most deployment scenarios, including side-by-side deployments with other Web services and applications.

Check following links

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159261.aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630447.aspx